# Python data validation with multiple possible keys per entry

Tags: python, json, validation, python-3.x, data-processing

I am trying to write a data deserializer/validator in python.  I have looked at several python tools for this, principally [colander](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/) and [voluptuous](https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous).  My input data will always be in JSON format.

The problem is, that I can't work out how to specify multiple possible locations for a given value.  An example should make this clearer.

Suppose I want to extract information called 'title'.  This will usually be at the root of JSON document in a field called 'title', but sometimes it will be in a level down as the 'doctitle' attribute of 'metadata'.  That is, sometimes my input data look like:

```
{
  'title' : 'Data I want to parse'
}
```

and sometimes like this

```
{
  'metadata' : {
    'doctitle' : 'Data I want to parse',
    'other_crap' : "I don't care about"
  }
}
```

And sometimes like other things.  I could potentially have many different patterns.

So what I'd really like to do is say something like:

```
schema = validator.Schema({'title':(['title',['metadata','doctitle']],validator.String)})
schema.validate(json.load(open('input_file')))
```

where the parser/validator will return something called 'title' by first trying JSON['title'], returning this if it validates, but if not trying JSON['metadata']['doctitle'] and seeing if it exists and validates.  That is, try each of the access patterns for finding the 'title' data in the source in order until one exists and validates or it runs out of options.

Does such a module exist or can I easily trick colander or voluptuous into behaving this way?  Or am I stuck writing my own solution from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You might try using the first schema. If it fails, use the second schema. If that fails, then your input is bad:

```
schema_1 = voluptuous.Schema({'title': str})
schema_2 = voluptuous.Schema({
        'metadata': {
            'doctitle': str,
            'other_crap': str
        }
    })

try:
    schema_1(data)
except voluptuous.MultipleInvalid:
    schema_2(data)
else:
    raise RuntimeError('Bad data!')
```

Comment: I guess this would work, but has several disadvantages.  Firstly, I have several fields I want to extract.  Ideally, I'd follow the modules philosophy and define all of them in one schema Schema({'title':str,'description':str}) etc.  With this approach I'd need one schema per variant, which is pretty ugly.  Secondly, I will have many possible schemas, not just the two toy examples I provided, so this will get messy and verbose quickly.  But if there's no better way I'll probably go with this.

Comment: Ultimately whatever validator you use is likely going to be limited by the JSON schema [standard](http://json-schema.org/). So if that standard doesn't allow for this sort of thing, you'll likely have to code around it. But I am not very familiar with JSON validators and schema, so I can't add too much in that direction. On the other hand, if you decide to go this route and have many schema to validate there's no need for it to get messy and verbose. Simply put your schema in a container and loop over them. If an exception is raised, simply `continue`. If you reach the end, the input was bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about this but can't you put all the posible name in the list and just iterate over all them trying each until you find one? In the case looking for an non-existing element raised an exception you could just pass it and keep searching.

Comment: You could introduce all the possible functions with their argumetns in a list as string and eval() them in order. Could that work?